# Callback Functions across computers?

Tags: python, callback, polling

I'm writing a python server/client app. If I serialize a function on the client and pass it to the server, can the server use it as a callback? I'm assuming there must be something extra I'd have to do as the client and server are communicating via packets, I just don't know what.

What I actually need is for the server to change one of the client's attributes (when the server is ready to accept another command), and I want an alternative to having the client continuously poll the server. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Twisted JSON RPC.
A recent SO post: [Python Twisted JSON RPC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738209/python-twisted-json-rpc)