# Json RPC Python Client

Tags: python, json

What is the easy way to making json rpc call from python?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738209/python-twisted-json-rpc.
It has some example code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [json-rpc for python](http://json-rpc.org/wiki/python-json-rpc).

Comment: The example on that link is out of date. See @pavlof99's answer for the latest docs

Answer (score 2):

Also there is [json-rpc](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/json-rpc) library, it supports python2.7, python3.2+, does not have dependencies and it`s protocol independent.

Answer (score 1):

json-wsp (implemented in Ladon) has a python client and a javascript client for browsers.

[Ladon](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ladon) (Supports both python 2 and 3)

[Python client](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~jakob-simon-gaarde/ladon/trunk/download/head:/jsonwspclient.py-20110408073624-ovbp2zk003q5bvfp-1/jsonwsp.py) (Python client can be used from shell too)

[Javascript client](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~jakob-simon-gaarde/ladon/trunk/download/head:/jsonclient.js-20110213221122-g9wj0q4yay8niipv-3/jsonwspclient.js)

Answer (score 0):

you need to create server and client script.
and you have to provide JSONRPCResponseManager and dispatcher.

from jsonrpc import JSONRPCResponseManager, dispatcher

something like
@Request.application
def application(request):
    # Dispatcher is dictionary {: callable}
    dispatcher["Hi"] = lambda s: s

```
response = JSONRPCResponseManager.handle(
    request.data, dispatcher)
return Response(response.json, mimetype='application/json')
```