# Using JSONRPC with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json-rpc, cross-domain-policy

**How do I get JSONRPC working properly with JQuery on the client-side, on the referenced types of calls?**

To represent my attempt, I've tried to create the smallest possible test-case:

#### Server[1]

```py
from txjsonrpc.web import jsonrpc
from twisted.web import server
from twisted.internet import reactor

class Math(jsonrpc.JSONRPC):
    def jsonrpc_add(self, a, b):
        return a+b

    def jsonrpc_echo(self, foo):
        return str(foo)

    def jsonrpc_hello(self):
        return u"Hello World!"

reactor.listenTCP(7080, server.Site(Math()))
reactor.run()
```

#### Client[2]

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Math is fun?!</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/datagraph/jquery-jsonrpc/master/jquery.jsonrpc.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $.jsonRPC.setup({
                    endPoint : 'http://localhost:7080',
                    namespace : ''
                });
                $("input#evaluate").click(function() {
                    $.jsonRPC.request('jsonrpc_echo', {
                        params : [$("textarea#input").val()],
                        success : function(data) {
                            $("<p />").text(data.result).appendTo($("p#result"));
                        },
                        error : function(data) {
                            $("<p />").text(data.error.message).appendTo($("p#result"));
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="result"></p>
        <p>
            <textarea name="input" id="input"></textarea>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input name="evaluate" id="evaluate" value="evaluate" type="button" />
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

1. Adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/4738563/1438003
2. Adapted from https://github.com/filonenko-mikhail/maxima-json-rpc/blob/master/examples/js-maxima-rpc-client.html

Comment: I'm neither getting expected output nor errors :/

Comment: There are several JSON-RPC plugins for jQuery. Which one are you using?

Comment: [JQuery-JSONRPC](https://github.com/datagraph/jquery-jsonrpc/), though admittedly it should be possible using just `stringify`, i.e.: without a plugin atop JQuery

Comment: Well can you tell (via Firebug or TamperData or some other debug tool) whether the HTTP request is being made?  Are there logs on the server?

Comment: Hmm: "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:7080/?tm=1342959087286. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin." - Is this where I use JSONP?!

Comment: If you're loading your page as a "file://" URL, then a request to that "localhost" URL is cross-domain. If you load your page from that same server, however, it should work.

Comment: Okay, I'm running it from localhost now, and all it's giving me is a "Load cancelled" error from JQuery. Also, in production I'll need to load it from file, since it'll be packaged into a PhoneGap app.

Comment: Well PhoneGap doesn't have cross-domain restrictions. I don't know what "Load cancelled" means.

Comment: I'm only getting the load cancelled error in Chrome, on the PhoneGap app I can't get any debug messages from the JS, it just isn't loading anything. :/